# Missing required parameter for publish-layer-version (aws cli)

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to publish the layer using AWS CLI

```sh
aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name layer --region us-west-2
```

This is the error message -

```sh
Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in input: "Content"
```

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/publish-layer-version.html) shows this example -

```sh
aws lambda publish-layer-version \
    --layer-name my-layer \
    --description "My Python layer" \
    --license-info "MIT" \
    --content S3Bucket=lambda-layers-us-west-2-123456789012,S3Key=layer.zip \
    --compatible-runtimes python3.6 python3.7
```

What value for the content param should I add if I don't use S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--zip-file`, instead of `--content`:

> The path to the zip file of the content you are uploading. Specify --zip-file or --content, but not both. Example: fileb://content.zip